# Apollo MockedProvider is throwing error 'Element type is invalid'

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-testing-library, react-apollo

I'm trying to test a React component that uses Apollo userQuery but I'm getting this error:

> console.error node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:209
>
> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.

Here is my test

```
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing'
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { customerList } from '../../mocks'
import { ListCustomers } from '../../queries'
import CustomerListContainer from '../CustomerListContainer'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: ListCustomers,
    },
    result: {
      data: customerList,
    },
  },
]

describe('components: <CustomerListContainer />', () => {
  it('renders customer list', () => {
    render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <CustomerListContainer customerRole="ADMIN" />
      </MockedProvider>
    )
  })
})
```

Here is the component I'm testing:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { CustomerList } from '../components'
import { ListCustomers } from '../queries'

const CustomerListContainer = ({ customerRole }: { customerRole: string }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(ListCustomers, {
    variables: {
      filter: {
        role: {
          eq: customerRole,
        },
      },
    },
  })

  if (error) return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

  return (
      <CustomerList customers={data.listCustomers.items} />
  )
}

export default CustomerListContainer
```

From my package.json:

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.7.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

For context I used Create React App.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upgrade to the latest version of react-scripts, in my case version 5.0.1.